# Handling rows selection with paginated server side data using react-query and cached users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-query, react-table

i am using Tanstack Query to fetch users for my table,  i've got server side paginated result depends of Page index and Page size. Every switch of page new query goes or if it is cached (e. g. when we enetered page, we fetch for that page data, then if we go to another and back we've got already fetched data). Now I am implementing row selection and i've got problem that if i want to select rows on all pages, table doesn't know about cached data only about data on page index it is. How can i include cached data or let know table about rows on another page?

```
  const [{ pageIndex, pageSize }, setPagination] =
    React.useState<PaginationState>({
      pageIndex: 1,
      pageSize: 10,
    });

  const pagination = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      pageIndex,
      pageSize,
    }),
    [pageIndex, pageSize]
  );
  const query = useUsers(pagination);
  const { data: users, isLoading } = query;
```

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { PaginationState } from '@tanstack/react-table';

import React from 'react';
import config from '../../../config';
import { PaginatedResult } from '../../../core/models/pagination/PaginatedResult';
import { User } from '../../../core/models/users/User';
import usersKeys from '../../../core/api/queries/users';
import serverSideDataUrlBuilder from '../../../core/helpers/serverSideDataUrlBuilder';

async function fetchUsers(pagination: PaginationState) {
  const urlBuilder = serverSideDataUrlBuilder(`${config.API.url}/users`);
  urlBuilder.clear();
  urlBuilder.addPagination(pagination.pageIndex, pagination.pageSize);
  const url = urlBuilder.build();

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
  });

  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch users');
  }

  const jsonResponse = await response.json();

  return jsonResponse as PaginatedResult<Array<User>>;
}

const useUsers = (pagination: PaginationState) =>
  useQuery<PaginatedResult<Array<User>>, Error>(
    [usersKeys.paginated(pagination)],
    () => fetchUsers(pagination),
    {
      select: React.useCallback(
        (data: PaginatedResult<Array<User>>) => data,
        []
      ),
    }
  );

export default useUsers;
```

```
 const handleSelectionChange = (value: string) => {
    const selectTableValue = getSelectTableValue(value);

    if (
      selectTableValue.label === 'Select all' &&
      selectTableValue.allPages
    ) {
      table.toggleAllRowsSelected(true);
    } else if (
      selectTableValue.label === 'Deselect all' &&
      selectTableValue.allPages
    ) {
      table.toggleAllRowsSelected(false);
    } else if (
      selectTableValue.label === 'Select all' &&
      !selectTableValue.allPages
    ) {
      table.toggleAllPageRowsSelected(true);
    } else if (
      selectTableValue.label === 'Deselect all' &&
      !selectTableValue.allPages
    ) {
      table.toggleAllPageRowsSelected(false);
    }
  };
```